# Difference between IsRequired(false) and omitting using it when adding properties (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

So I'm wondering about the difference between setting IsRequired() to false and simply not using it when setting up a property for a database table.
Is the default behaviour when not using IsRequired() to allow the property to be nullable?

I don't have trial and error examples, just noticed on a project that whether it's false or not null, the table in the database displays the property as nullable either way. So is there a difference between not using IsRequired() at all or using it and setting it to false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's safe to assume that if you don't explictly declare a property as not-required, or you do so explicitly but set it to false, then you will get the same result.

I've had a quick dig around the EF Core source code, and the nearest I can come up with a definitive answer is the [constructor](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/dfed0f576f6d6205af825d6ce9fb997bfc350d50/src/EFCore/Metadata/Internal/ForeignKey.cs#L14) for `ForeignKey` :

```
public ForeignKey(
    IReadOnlyList<Property> dependentProperties,
    Key principalKey,
    EntityType dependentEntityType,
    EntityType principalEntityType,
    ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
{
    ...
    _isRequired = DefaultIsRequired;
```

and

```
private bool DefaultIsRequired
    => !Properties.Any(p => p.IsNullable);
```